# Swift cannot use any variables inside of struct

Tags: swift, struct, sprite-kit

I have a struct, Trajectory.

```
struct Trajectory {

        var invisibleBall: SKSpriteNode!
        var count = Int()
        var copiedNodes = Array<SKSpriteNode>()


    }
```

When I try to use any of the variables inside of Trajectory  get this error, `Instance member 'invisibleBall' cannot be used on type 'GameScene.Trajectory'`  Why is this. I have used structs this same way many times before.

```
    Trajectory.invisibleBall = self.childNode(withName: "//invisibleBall")
    //this is where i get the error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not creating an instance from `Trajectory`, you should do:

```
let trajectory = Trajectory()
trajectory.invisibleBall = self.childNode(withName: "//invisibleBall")
```

Or if you are *pretty* sure that you would use it directly from the struct, then you should declare `invisibleBall` as a *static* property:

```
struct Trajectory {

        static var invisibleBall: SKSpriteNode!
        var count = Int()
        var copiedNodes = Array<SKSpriteNode>()
}
```

then you would be able to:

```
Trajectory.invisibleBall = self.childNode(withName: "//invisibleBall")
```

Comment: Oh yea i completely forgot to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize a `Trajectory` object.  So you could simply change your code to:

```
let trajectory = Trajectory()
trajectory.invisibleBall = self.childNode(withName: "//invisibleBall")
```

Comment: @dfri Oh, I agree.  I guess I'm just assuming that this sample is being assigned to a variable in the asker's example, as the same is true for that original post.

Comment: @dfri OK, point taken.  It's still valid code, though I agree that it's useless.  I edited my answer.